# JavaScript automatically unsets element class after onkeyup function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am coding a suggest box and after the onkeyup function sets the background of the span by changing the class, the class goes away. It will flash the background for a split second on an arrow press then unsets the class. I have never seen this behavior and don't know how to fix it. Why would the class become unset after the function returns?

```
 this.setHighlight = function(spans, lit, change) {
        if (lit == undefined) {
            // we know it's the first highlight    
            if (change == 1) {
                spans[spans.length - 1].className = 'highlight';
            }
            else if (change == -1) {
                spans[0].className = 'highlight';
            }
        }
        else {
            // remove the old highlight
            spans[lit].className = '';
            // set the new highlight
            spans[lit + change].className = 'highlight';
        }
    };
```

There is part of the script that sets the name, it is called from a switch lower in the script that handles the keypress event.

edit:

```
      switch (e.keyCode) {
            // determine how the box highlighting will shift
            case 38:
                // the user has presssed the up arrow
                console.log('up');
                this.setHighlight(spans, lit, 1);
                break;

            case 40:
                // the user has pressed down
                console.log('down');
                this.setHighlight(spans, lit, -1);
                break;
```

that is the calling switch. the html is just

```
<input type="text" name="whatever" onkeyup="getSuggest(this, 'suggest_type', event)" />
```

Comment: The code where you set up the event handler, and possibly the relevant HTML, would be very interesting.

Comment: Would it not be easier to just highlight the relevant element once it's in focus by firing the `onfocus` event?

Comment: @ChrisKempen That will not work here since I am using span elements that need to be keyed through with the arrow keys. Nothing would be happening to trigger focus on the spans.

Comment: Oh I see! My apologies...I'm going to vote up @Pointy's comment, because - short of just rewriting a solution for you and not helping you with your actual problem - I'm not sure where the problem could lie...thoughts on using jQuery to make life a little easier?

Comment: Yeah I don't know either. I like to write my own solutions to problems like these and have never had a problem like this before. My gut tells me it's some sort of scoping or reference issue but I just can't find it. This is all the relevant code. The only other part of the function just retrieves the suggestions from the DB. Something here is what is tripping everything up.

Comment: When does the `lit` variable get set?

Comment: lit is set right before the switch. a for loop goes through the spans that are contained in the suggest div and checks them to see if any are of the class 'highlight'. If not then the function handles undefined as there has been no arrow keys hit yet since the suggest div was spawned.

Comment: Yep, this is what @Pointy and I are talking about, seeing all of the relevant code ;) Interesting problem, and I can't move this into a chat discussion yet based on your rep, but I'm going to post a solution as an answer below...watch this space!

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it has something to do with the way you're setting the `lit` variable, and during my experimentation I also noticed that you might have had your `change` variable set the wrong way around in your `keyCode` switch statement, AND I also switched the initial highlighting in the test for an undefined `lit` to make more sense. I'm also assuming `lit` is an integer when it's defined.

Anyways, plugging in your code and filling in the blanks, I managed to get this working successfully. First, the CSS in the HEAD section:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .highlight
    {
        font-weight: bold;
        border: 1px solid #333333;
    }
</style>
```

Next, the Javascript in the HEAD section:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    var lit = undefined;

    function getSuggest(element, str, e)
    {
        var container = document.getElementById("span_container");
        var spans = container.getElementsByTagName("SPAN");

        for (var i=0; i<spans.length; i++)
        {
            if (spans[i].className == "highlight")
            {
                lit = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        switch (e.keyCode)
        {
            // determine how the box highlighting will shift
            case 38:
                // the user has pressed up
                setHighlight(spans, lit, -1);
                break;

            case 40:
                // the user has pressed down
                setHighlight(spans, lit, 1);
                break;
        }
    }

    function setHighlight(spans, lit, change)
    {
        if (lit == undefined)
        {
            // we know it's the first highlight    
            if (change == 1)
            {
                spans[0].className = 'highlight';
            }
            else if (change == -1)
            {
                spans[spans.length - 1].className = 'highlight';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // remove the old highlight
            spans[lit].className = '';

            // set the new highlight
            var new_lit = (lit + change);
            if (new_lit >= spans.length)
                new_lit = 0;
            else if (new_lit < 0)
                new_lit = spans.length - 1;

            spans[new_lit].className = 'highlight';
        }
    }

</script>
```

And finally, some silly HTML in the BODY section to make it all work:

```
<input type='text' onkeyup='getSuggest(this, "suggest_type", event)' />

<div id="span_container">
    <span>one</span><br />
    <span>two</span><br />
    <span>three</span><br />
    <span>four</span><br />
    <span>five</span><br />
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)